# blogdown::new_post not working with date=""

Tags: r, blogdown

The function blogdown::new_post() recently stopped working for me with the parameter date="".

here's the line of code:

> blogdown:::new_post("home", kind = "default-frontpage", open=F, date="",  subdir="", ext = ".Rmd")

it gives this error:

> Error in if (tryCatch(date > Sys.Date(), error = function(e) FALSE)) warning("The date of the post is in the future: ",  :
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Someone else who works in the lab has tried to reproduce this error on their computer, but wasn't able to. All of my R packages are up to date, according to RStudio.

When I call Sys.Date(), it returns today's date as: "2020-11-29"

I can specify a date in new_post(), but it would require re-writing a substantial amount of our code, and it seems like this changes the automatically generated title of the post.

Could anyone suggest a next step?

Thanks a bunch!

Caleb

Comment: You can look at the code for `new_post()` by typing `new_post`. In the code you'll see that you can prevent this check from being run by clearing  the option `blogdown.warn.future` or setting it to `FALSE`. If you pass an empty string to this code, `tryCatch` will return `NA`  and `if` will raise the error you see.

Comment: I don't think this is due to a recent change in **blogdown**. The relevant code that triggered the error [was introduced in a very early version of **blogdown**](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/commit/fde88cd4686570c0851d15b083919051e36e7910). Anyway, I just pushed a fix. See the answer below. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 0):

[I just fixed this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/commit/ece8b5832fac861eb8b353626ce4924fd4aef5ff) on Github, and you may try

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')
```

Thanks for the report!